# R package "forestplot": Error message re: identifying the upper/lower boundaries from the input matrix

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'd be grateful for your help. I'm using the forestplot R package to create a forest plot. It was going well.

```
library(forestplot)                  
test_data <- data.frame(
    coef = c(1.53, 1.56, 1.11, 1.35, 1.00, 0.94, 1.03),
    low = c(1.43, 1.38, 1.08, 1.05, 0.91, 0.87, 0.95),
    high = c(1.64, 1.76, 1.15, 1.75, 1.10, 1.01, 1.11),
    boxsize = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
)
row_names <- cbind(
    c("Variable", "BMI", "WHR", "Diabetes", "Insulin resistance", "LDL", "HDL", "ApoB"),
    c("SNPs", "807", "368", "386", "53", "213", "510", "241"),
    c("OR (95% CI)", "1·53 (1·43−1·64)", "1·56 (1·38−1·76)", "1·11 (1·08−1·15)", "1·35 (1·05−1·75)", "1·00 (0·91−1·10)", "0·94 (0·87−1·01)", "1·03 (0·95−1·11)"),
    c("p-value", "6·72E−35", "2·90E−12", "6·61E−10", "0·02", "0·97", "0·083", "0·53")
)
test_data <- rbind(rep(NA, 3), test_data)
forestplot(
    labeltext = row_names,
    xlab = "Odds ratio",
    test_data[, c("coef", "low", "high")],
    is.summary = FALSE,
    boxsize = test_data$boxsize,
    zero = 1,
    cex = 0.1,
    align = TRUE,
    xlog = FALSE,
    graphwidth = unit(1.5, "snpc"),
    col = fpColors(lines = "royalblue", box = "darkblue")
)
```

I've been adding one variable at a time and plotting my graph after the addition of each to make sure there were no errors introduced at each step. It was all going well until I added my eighth variable, "Triglycerides", and its associated numbers:

```
library(forestplot)                  
test_data <- data.frame(
    coef = c(1.53, 1.56, 1.11, 1.35, 1.00, 0.94, 1.03, 1.15),
    low = c(1.43, 1.38, 1.08, 1.05, 0.91, 0.87, 0.95, 1.07),
    high = c(1.64, 1.76, 1.15, 1.75, 1.10, 1.01, 1.11, 1.11),
    boxsize = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
)
row_names <- cbind(
    c("Variable", "BMI", "WHR", "Diabetes", "Insulin resistance", "LDL", "HDL", "ApoB", "Triglycerides"),
    c("SNPs", "807", "368", "386", "53", "213", "510", "241", "427"),
    c("OR (95% CI)", "1·53 (1·43−1·64)", "1·56 (1·38−1·76)", "1·11 (1·08−1·15)", "1·35 (1·05−1·75)", "1·00 (0·91−1·10)", "0·94 (0·87−1·01)", "1·03 (0·95−1·11)", "1·15 (1·07−1·11)"),
    c("p-value", "6·72E−35", "2·90E−12", "6·61E−10", "0·02", "0·97", "0·083", "0·53", "2·14E−4")
)
test_data <- rbind(rep(NA, 3), test_data)
forestplot(
    labeltext = row_names,
    xlab = "Odds ratio",
    test_data[, c("coef", "low", "high")],
    is.summary = FALSE,
    boxsize = test_data$boxsize,
    zero = 1,
    cex = 0.1,
    align = TRUE,
    xlog = FALSE,
    graphwidth = unit(1.5, "snpc"),
    col = fpColors(lines = "royalblue", box = "darkblue")
)
```

On adding this eighth variable, I now receive the following error message:

> Error in prFpConvertMultidimArray(mean) :
> Sorry did not manage to correctly identify the upper/lower boundaries from the input matrix.

I can't spot a syntax error here, and I'm really at a loss as to why this has only just happened. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: your `high` for tgl is less than `coef`, the function `prFpConvertMultidimArray ` checks this condition `!all(mean <= upper, na.rm = TRUE)` which returns true for that variable

Comment: Ah! What a schoolboy error! Thank you so much for spotting that - you're a star.